# SSIS XML XSLT transformation task

Tags: xml, ssis

I have an SSIS XML Task that I'm using to try and reformat some XML output into pretty HTML.  Here is the XML

```
<RootNode><row><ProcessName>RefreshDbnSr1FromP01</ProcessName><StartDateAndTime>2011-09-21T15:13:56</StartDateAndTime><AverageSeconds>2562</AverageSeconds></row><row><ProcessName>RefreshDbnSr1FromP01</ProcessName><StartDateAndTime>2011-09-21T15:29:45</StartDateAndTime><AverageSeconds>2562</AverageSeconds></row><row><ProcessName>RefreshDbnSr1FromP01</ProcessName><StartDateAndTime>2011-09-21T15:44:07</StartDateAndTime><AverageSeconds>2562</AverageSeconds></row></RootNode>
```

And then here is the XSLT I'm using to transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/RootNode">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
            <th>ProcessName</th>
            <th>StartDateAndTime</th>
            <th>AverageSeconds</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProcessName" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="StartDateAndTime" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="AverageSeconds" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It seems to work fine in IE.  (if I add the header it works.) But the output that the XML task exports looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>RefreshDbnSr1FromP012011-09-21T15:13:562562RefreshDbnSr1FromP012011-09-21T15:29:452562RefreshDbnSr1FromP012011-09-21T15:44:072562
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like the XML task never saw your stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your XSLT before the  element:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

See the sample stylesheet in this blog post:
http://geekswithblogs.net/LifeLongTechie/archive/2011/02/02/using-ssis-to-send-a-html-e-mail-message-with-built-in.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I ended up using the instructions in there and changed my XML to PATH, ROOT.  The xslt schema was much simpler in that example as well.  adding the xsl:output didn't seem to help though.  It works like a champ now.